The category of triangulated categories is a 2-category
$\def\C{\mathcal{C}}
\def\D{\mathcal{D}}
\def\Triang{\mathsf{Triang}}
\def\Trans{\mathsf{Trans}}
\def\D{\mathcal{D}}$A category with translation is a pair $(\C,T)$ where $\C$ is a category and $T:\C\to\C$ is an auto-equivalence. A 1-morphism of categories with translation $(\C,T)\to(\C',T')$ is a functor $F:\C\to\C'$ along with a natural isomorphism $\xi:FT\cong T'F$. Given morphisms of categories with translation $(F,\xi),(G,\zeta):(\C,T)\to(\C',T')$, a 2-morphism $(F,\xi)\Rightarrow(G,\zeta)$ is a natural transformation $\eta:F\Rightarrow G$ such that
$$
\label{sqr}\tag{1}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
FT@>{\xi}>>T'F\\
@V\eta_T VV@VVT'\eta V\\
GT@>>\zeta> T'G
\end{CD}
$$
commutes. A 2-morphism is also called a transnatural transformation. Commutativity of \eqref{sqr} is called the transnaturality condition.
Denote $\Trans$ to the collection of categories with translations along with the 1 and 2-morphisms. I have two questions:
(Q1). Why is $\Trans$ a 2-category? (What is horizontal composition?)
(Q2). Do you know a reference for the result in Q1?

Motivation: The category $\Triang$ of triangulated categories becomes a subcategory of $\Trans$ with 1-morphisms and 2-morphisms defined as below. Proving that $\Trans$ is a 2-category would imply that $\Triang$ is a 2-category.
Definition. A 1-morphism of triangulated categories $(\D,T)\to(\D',T')$ is a 1-morphism of categories with translation $(F,\xi):(\D,T)\to(\D',T')$ such that for every distinguished triangle $A\to B\to C\xrightarrow{h} TA$ in $\D$, the triangle $FA\to FB\to FC\xrightarrow{\xi_A\circ Fh}T'FC$ is distinguished in $\D'$. A 1-morphism in $\Triang$ is also called a triangulated functor (or exact functor by some authors).
Definition. Let $(F,\xi),(G,\zeta):(\D,T)\to(\D',T')$ be triangulated functors between triangulated categories. A trinatural transformation $(F,\xi)\Rightarrow (G,\zeta)$ is, for each object $A\in\D$, a morphism $\eta_A:FA\to GA$, subject to the following property: For every distinguished triangle $A\to B\to C\xrightarrow{h} TA$ in $\D$, the diagram
$$
\tag{2}\label{trinat}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 FA@>>> FB @>>> FC@>>> T'FA\\
 @VVV@VVV@VVV@VVV\\
 GA@>>> GB @>>> GC@>>> T'GA
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, where the vertical maps are given by $\eta_A,\eta_B,\eta_C$, and the last top and bottom arrows are $\xi_A\circ F(h)$ and $\zeta_A\circ G(h)$, respectively.
Lemma. $(F,\xi),(G,\zeta):(\D,T)\to(\D',T')$ be triangulated functors between triangulated categories. A collection of morphisms $\eta_A:FA\to GA$, $A\in\D$, define a trinatural transformation $(F,\xi)\Rightarrow (G,\zeta)$ if and only if they define a transnatural transformation $(F,\xi)\Rightarrow (G,\zeta)$.
Proof. Write $\eta=\{\eta_A\}_{A\in\D}$.
Suppose first we have a trinatural transformation. Let $A\to B$ be any morphism in $\D$. Extend it to a distinguished triangle $A\to B\to C\to TA$. Commutativity of the left square of \eqref{trinat} implies naturality of $\eta$. On the other hand, the triangle $A\to 0\to TA\xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}}TA$ is distinguished in $\D$. Hence commutativity of the right square of \eqref{trinat} realized in this triangle becomes the transnaturality condition \eqref{sqr}.
Conversely, assume $\eta$ is transnatural and let $A\to B\to C\to TA$ be a distinguished triangle in $\D$. Then the first and middle square of \eqref{trinat} commutes, by naturality of $\eta$. The right square of \eqref{trinat} decomposes as
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
FC@>{Fh}>> FTA@>{\xi_A}>> T'FA\\
@VVV@VVV@VVV\\
GC@>{\smash{Gh}}>> GTA @>{\smash{\zeta_A}}>> T'GA
\end{CD}
$$
In this diagram, the left (resp., right) square commutes by naturality (resp., transnaturality) of $\eta$. $\square$

$\def\Trans{\mathsf{Trans}}$Here's an answer to Q1. Note that transnaturality (commutativity of \eqref{sqr}) amounts to the equality of 2-cells:

The horizontal composition in $\Trans$ is defined to be standard horizontal composition in the 2-category $\mathsf{Cat}$ of 1-categories. If we check that this operation is well-defined (i.e., horizontal operation in $\Trans$ gives back a 2-morphism in $\Trans$), then it will follow that $\Trans$ is a 2-category. All other axioms of a 2-category (understood as in [R, Definition 1.7.8]) follow from the fact that these hold in $\mathsf{Cat}$. Thus, the forgetful functor $\Trans\to\mathsf{Cat}$ sending a category with translation to its underlying category will promote to a 2-functor.
Consider then the following diagram in $\Trans$:

For simplicity, we will abuse notation by denoting with same letter $T$ to the translation of $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$. We have to verify that the horizontal composition $\beta *\alpha$ (performed in $\mathsf{Cat}$) is transnatural (i.e., it defines a 2-morphism $\beta *\alpha:(GF,\zeta_F\circ G\xi)\Rightarrow(G'F',\zeta'_{F'}\circ G'\xi')$ in $\Trans$).
By the middle four interchange law and transnaturality of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we get the sequence of equalities [1, 2, 3]:



As desired.
